Best OpenGL buffer usage hint when replacing entire buffer with glBufferSubData() every frame?
I am working on a fork of SFML that targets relatively Modern OpenGL and Emscripten. I implemented batching (online demo) and I'm wondering if it could be optimized even further.
At the moment, mostly due to SFML API constraints, this is what I am doing:

Create a vertex buffer and index buffer once at the beginning of the application via glBufferData.

Every frame, loop through all game objects and produce pre-transformed vertices into a huge CPU buffer (basically a std::vector<Vertex>). I do the same for indices.

Every frame, copy the entire vertex/index CPU buffers to the GPU via glBufferSubData.

Render everything at once with a single draw call using glDrawElements.


I am currently using GL_STREAM_DRAW as the usage hint for the buffer. However, it is unclear if that's the optimal choice looking at the documentation:


STREAM: The data store contents will be modified once and used at most a few times.
STATIC: The data store contents will be modified once and used many times.
DYNAMIC: The data store contents will be modified repeatedly and used many times.


In my case, the "data store contents" will be completely replaced and used once per frame, but the same buffer will be reused constantly during the execution of the program, so I am not sure how to interpret the documentation.
Is my choice of GL_STREAM_DRAW here correct?

Have you tried glMapBuffer and ping-ponging the vertex data (format permitting)? A DMA flush (should be*) much faster than glBufferSubData. *That said, performance with OpenGL has always been very much device-dependent for me.

@Wedge: tried glMapBuffer in two ways: (1) trivially use it to copy the entire data; and (2) a complicated solution managing a dynamically-resizable buffer and directly producing pre-transformed vertices in that buffer.
(2) was promising as it provided a big speedup, but it had a weird problem: after rendering a massive amount of game objects for a while, and then reducing the game object amount to something sensible, drawing performance tanked for the rest of the application lifetime. No clue why... This is the code: https://gist.github.com/vittorioromeo/ca61bc84faa984f89e5180e07aad9778

@Wedge: performance speedup with the second solution also was inconsistent between desktop OpenGL, desktop ES (via ANGLE), and Emscripten. The added complexity and (most importantly) the weird unexplicable performance bug made me scrap it, but I'd like to revisit it if I manage to figure out what was going wrong...

Maybe this answer is useful here? From what I've read, the definitive "best usage hint" for any situation doesn't exist. Your best bet may be to try all three, profiled on different hardware.

@VittorioRomeo Probably a driver bug. Implied by what #Yun said, you may need to write multiple different versions of the rendering engine just with OpenGL. The most robust thing you can try is implement every possible solution you can think reasonable, and have the engine profile and configure itself per-install (or at the user's request).
